# Can i import wall posts from users wall into my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

How I can import post from user's wall in Facebook ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) and GET the **feed** connection of the [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user)

See Facebook [developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.get/).